# what is wrong with my loop cp one liner?

Tags: bash

I have a dir called `0_400x24_multi_newton20` in the current directory. And I want to copy it as 2_400x24_multi_newton20, 4_400x24_multi_newton20, ....

so I use below code

```
for((i=2;i<21;i=i+2)); do cp -r "0_400x24_multi_newton20/" "$i_400x24_multi_newton20/"; done
```

however it warns me that

> cp: cannot create directory `/0_400x24_multi_newton20': Permission
>   denied

On the other hand

```
cp -r "0_400x24_multi_newton20/" "2_400x24_multi_newton20/"
```

works

So how to do it correctly?

Comment: The error message has a leading `/` but your code doesn't. Are you sure *this* is the code that produced the error?

Comment: @P.P. yes see here http://pasteboard.co/etv3Jw8f6.png

Comment: in your case, the shell looks for a variable called `i_400x24_multi_newton20`, which is undefined. so the `cp` command gets expanded as `cp -r "0_400x24_multi_newton20/" "/"`, as a result, the command tries to copy `0_400x24_multi_newton20` to the root `/`, thus, you get the error because you do not have write permission on `/`. The answer @M. Dogru provides below fixes the issue.

Comment: @zhliu03 Thank you, that is good explanation. So I just found this sentence "${parameter} is same as $parameter, i.e., value of the variable parameter. In certain contexts, only the less ambiguous ${parameter} form works." So does it means in any case, we should use ${i} and will be safe?

Comment: yes, it looks to me a good practice to always use ${i}

Comment: @zhliu03 Thanks : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May by ;

```
for((i=2;i<21;i=i+2)); do cp -r "0_400x24_multi_newton20/" "${i}_400x24_multi_newton20/"; done
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. It works! but why? the tutorials I see are always `$i`

Comment: $i is not expanding so should use {}

Comment: The problem here is not `$i is not explanding` but the shell expands `$i_400x24_multi_newton20` as a whole and since it doesn't exist, replaces it with an empty value.

Comment: @sjsam Thank you very much, sjsam. Now I really understand the whole thing.